# Where to learn LC3 with proper full explanations?

Tags: lc3

This may seem rather silly, but there actually are hardly any resources to learn LC-3. I can't manage to seem to find a proper in depth analysis of the subject and explain how things work, I mean sure, you can find simple definitions and what certain op/pseudo-op codes do, but nothing written in full and fully explained.

If someone could do a full analysis of the following:

```
; Hello name in LC-3 assembler

    .orig   x3000
    lea r0, what
    puts
    lea r1, name
; typical assembly language hack coming up
    add r1, r1, #-1
char        getc
    putc
    add r2, r0, #-10
    brz completed; was a newline
    str r0, r1, #0
    add r1, r1, #1
    brnzp   char
completed   lea r0, hello
    puts
    halt
```

That would probably extremely lengthy, but also very appreciated. (Maybe this is the first stack post for a full analysis of LC-3 code resource?)
p.s I don't expect the person who answers to explain what each op/pseudo op code does but at least be very specific about **how** the operator performs and does its work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I mostly learned how LC3 worked from plugging in code and stepping through it. Though I would reference [Appendix A](http://highered.mheducation.com/sites/0072467509/student_view0/appendices_a__b__c__d____e.html) in the book a LOT.

```
; Hello name in LC-3 assembler

    .orig   x3000                ; Starting place in memory for our code
    lea r0, what                 ; Load the memory address of variable what
    puts                         ; Print the string who's memory address is stored in R0
    lea r1, name                 ; Load the memory address of the variable name into R1
; typical assembly language hack coming up
    add r1, r1, #-1              ; Subtract 1 from R1, then store into R1
    char        getc             ; Get a single char from the user, store into R0
    putc                         ; Print that same char to the console
    add r2, r0, #-10             ; R2 = R0 - 10
    brz completed                ; If the user presses ENTER (Ascii 10) 
                                 ; and we've subtracted 10 then we'll get a 0, exit program
    str r0, r1, #0               ; Store the value of R0 into memory[R1 + 0]
    add r1, r1, #1               ; R1 = R1 + 1
    brnzp   char                 ; Jump to Clear no matter what
completed   lea r0, hello        ; Load the memory address of variable hello into R0
    puts                         ; Print the string stored in hello
    halt                         ; Stop the program
```

Comment: Thanks for the info, by the way, how would I fill a register, lets say 3, with the number 40? or 255?

Comment: I'm glad it was helpful, if you wouldn't mind marking it as answered that would definitely help. To store a large value into a register you would need the value of 40 or 255 stored in a variable or another register. If that value is stored in another register then you would need to clear R3 and then add the two together. If from a variable then just load that value into R3 using the LD command.